# android:state_selected for ListView

Tags: android, android-widget

I have color state list resource which defines the listSelector for my ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/listview_selector_pressed" />

    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/listview_selector_focused" />

    <item 
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/listview_selector_selected" />

</selector>
```

Now, I know how to put a ListView item in the "pressed" and "focused" state, but I can't figure out what puts a ListView item in the "selected" state. ListView::getSelectedItem always returns null.

I'm running in the emulator but thoughts on how to trigger this "selected" state on a device are also welcome.

Comment: use trackball/d-pad to select item (try it on emulator) ... i don't know why but it is not working when listview is in touchmode

Comment: trackball seems to bring the item in the "focused" state.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/touch-mode.html i think that it's selected state

Comment: lol. The article above clears all doubts. Seems like it was written for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to figure out this,but FYI,listview cannot have selected item.Item is clicked onto that and that would be caught by `listview.setOnItemClickLister(..)`.

So simply from your code,when you will click the item onto listview,it will call pressed state.putting selected state is of no use in listview.

You will always have just 3 states of list item: normal,hower and pressed!

Comment: "but FYI,listview cannot have selected" this is not true ... you can select listview item with keyboard/trackball/d-pad .... remeber that not all android devices had touchscreen

Comment: but what exactly selected state mean? i mean,it is like hower state only..isn't it? or it is different?

Comment: Well from what I can see, I never  seem to put the listview item into the selected state. It seems to be in the "focused" state if I use the trackball or keyboard.

Comment: yes...focused means hover.simple! it means similar thing.but selected state...i am yet having doubt!!

Comment: it's selected not focused  ... but only if view is NOT in touch mode, please read this http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/touch-mode.html

Comment: lol. The article above clears all doubts. Seems like it was written for me :)